# How can I print a livecharts2 chart using PrintDocument?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, document, livecharts

I have several graphs made with livecharts2. They need to be able to print as seperate charts (which I can do with PrintDialog.PrintVisual), but also together with other measurements in one document (which will be turned into a pdf using a pdf printer driver.

Now, the charts display fine and using PrintVisual they print too,  but when trying to create a DocumentPaginator, the page stays very empty. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my Viewmodel (mostly taken from the sample on the livecharts2 site):

```
using LiveChartsCore;
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TestGraphPrintApp
{
    class ViewModel
    {
        private ICommand _printCommand;


        public ISeries[] Series { get; set; }
            = new ISeries[]
            {
                new LineSeries<double>
                {
                    Values = new double[] { 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 6 },
                    Fill = null
                }
            };

        public ICommand PrintCommand => _printCommand ?? (_printCommand = new RelayCommand<Visual>((param) =>
        {
            var dialog = new PrintDialog();
            bool? result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
            {
                ChartPaginator paginator = new ChartPaginator(this, new System.Windows.Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight));
                dialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "test");
            }
        }, obj => true));
    }
}
```

I know I shouldn't do the printing code in the ViewModel, but for the example it'll do.

Now the xaml is also mostly taken from the livecharts2 example, with the addition of the datatemplate for printing.

```
<Window x:Class="TestGraphPrintApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WPF;assembly=LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WPF"        
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestGraphPrintApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PrintSampleChartDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel}">           
                <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding Series}" AnimationsSpeed="0" Width="800" Height="600"/>           
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <StackPanel>
        <lvc:CartesianChart Name="Chart" Width="800" Height="380" AnimationsSpeed="0"
        Series="{Binding Series}">
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
        <Button Content="Print" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding PrintCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Chart}"/>
    </StackPanel>   
</Window>
```

And last, but not least, the paginator:

```
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WPF;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace TestGraphPrintApp
{
    class ChartPaginator : DocumentPaginator
    {
        private ViewModel _chart;        
        
        public ChartPaginator(ViewModel chart, Size pageSize)
        {
            _chart = chart;
            PageSize = pageSize;
        }

        public override bool IsPageCountValid => true;
        public override int PageCount => 1;
        public override Size PageSize { get; set; }
        public override IDocumentPaginatorSource Source => null;
        public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
        {            
            if (!(App.Current.MainWindow.Resources["PrintSampleChartDataTemplate"] is DataTemplate template))
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not find a DataTemplate for printing.");
            }            
            var contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter
            {
                Content = _chart,
                ContentTemplate = template,
                Width = 800,
                Height = 600
                
            };
            contentPresenter.Measure(this.PageSize);
            contentPresenter.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, this.PageSize.Width, this.PageSize.Height));
            contentPresenter.UpdateLayout();            
            return new DocumentPage(contentPresenter, this.PageSize, new Rect(), new Rect());
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you should wait until the chart is Loaded. The control takes quite a while to initialize so just handle the Loaded event to trigger the actual printing. But why do you create the paginator in the first place? Why would you load the expensive chart a second time while it is already loaded and rendered? You should stay with the first solution that prints the Visual of the already rendered control. Will improve performance. Depending on the size of the chart (and number of data models to render) this improvement is expected to be significant.

Comment: Unfortunenately, printing all measurements in a report including all the graphs is not optional. How do I get to the Loaded event of a control that only "exists" in the ContentPresenter? Weird enough, the content presenter doesn't show any visual or logical childeren.

Comment: ContentPresenter itself is not rendered. Its Content is rendered. If the Content is not a FrameworkElement you usually define a DataTemplate to tell the ContentPresenter what to render.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the `FrameworkElement` to a visual tree and render it before you can print it. This way it will be properly measured and the `Visual` is properly initialized. Of course, using `PrintDialog.PrintVisual` with an existing element that is already a child of the visual tree will omit this requirement.

Some design considerations:

- In an MVVM environment, the printing has to be done in the *View*. *View Model* classes don't handle *View* objects and therefore don't handle *any* sort of dialogs.
- The `ChartPaginator` should not explicitly depend on resources defined in the application. Instead pass such dependencies as an argument (for example constructor or property argument). This is because details like resource keys and the actual location (`ResourceDictionary`) of the resources should be hidden in order to enhance the design (e.g. extensibility).
- Accessing the static `Application.Current.MainWindow` property from outside of the referenced main `Window` indicates a design smell, which is usually solved by moving the calling code to the main `Window`.
- There is not benefit in restricting the accepted parameter type to `ViewModel` (in your `ChartPaginator` type). A `ContentPresenter` can display any type (`object`) as long as the appropriate `DataTemplate` is provided. This will make your class highly reusable - for free.
- Don't forget to let your binding source (e.g. `ViewModel`) implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (even if the properties won't change)

### Solution

To temporarily add the element to the visual tree you should create a helper class. This helper will manage the lifetime of the visualized elements. This means it will insert the element into the visual tree and remove it afterwards.

The usage of this helper looks as follows:

```xml
<VirtualElementHost x:Name="VirtualElementHost" />
```

```cs
// The element that is not a child of the visual tree
var someElementToPrint = new FrameworkElement();

// Dispose the scope object to end the lifetime of the initilaized element
using ElementLifetimeScope elementLifetimeScope = this.VirtualElementHost.CreateVirtualizedElementLifetimeScope();

// Temporarily render the element in order to initialize the Visual properly
await elementLifetimeScope.LoadElementAsync(someElementToPrint);

/* Use the activated element before its lifetime is ended 
   by calling 'ElementLifetimeScope.Dispose', for example via 'using' statement or declaration.
   Disposal will trigger the element to be removed from the visual tree.
*/
```

**VirtualElementHost.cs**

```cs
public class VirtualElementHost : FrameworkElement
{
  protected override int VisualChildrenCount => this.VisualChildren.Count;
  private VisualCollection VisualChildren { get; }
  private TaskCompletionSource TaskCompletionSource { get; set; }

  public VirtualElementHost()
  {
    this.VisualChildren = new VisualCollection(this);
    this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
  }

  public ElementLifetimeScope CreateVirtualizedElementLifetimeScope() => new ElementLifetimeScope(this);

  protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    => index < 0 || index >= this.VisualChildren.Count
      ? throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
      : this.VisualChildren[index];

  protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  {
    var maxDesiredSize = new Size();
    foreach (UIElement child in this.VisualChildren)
    {
      child.Measure(constraint);
      double maxWidth = Math.Max(maxDesiredSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Width);
      double maxHeight = Math.Max(maxDesiredSize.Height, child.DesiredSize.Height);
      maxDesiredSize = new Size(maxWidth, maxHeight);
    }

    return maxDesiredSize;
  }

  protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
  {
    foreach (UIElement child in this.VisualChildren)
    {
      child.Arrange(new Rect(child.DesiredSize));
    }

    return arrangeBounds;
  }

  internal void Virtualize(FrameworkElement element)
  {
    this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    _ = this.VisualChildren.Add(element);
    InvalidateMeasure();
  }

  internal void Reset()
  {
    this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    this.VisualChildren.Clear();
  }

  private void OnElementLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => this.TaskCompletionSource.SetResult();
}
```

**ElementLifetimeScope.cs**

```cs
public class ElementLifetimeScope : IDisposable
{
  private bool disposedValue;
  private VirtualElementHost VirtualElementHost { get; }
  private TaskCompletionSource TaskCompletionSource { get; set; }

  internal ElementLifetimeScope(VirtualElementHost virtualElementHost) => this.VirtualElementHost = virtualElementHost;

  public async Task LoadElementAsync(FrameworkElement element)
  {
    element.Loaded += OnElementLoaded;
    this.TaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource();
    this.VirtualElementHost.Virtualize(element);
    await this.TaskCompletionSource.Task;
  }

  private void OnElementLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => this.TaskCompletionSource.SetResult();

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (!this.disposedValue)
    {
      if (disposing)
      {
        this.VirtualElementHost.Reset();
      }

      // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override finalizer
      // TODO: set large fields to null
      this.disposedValue = true;
    }
  }

  // // TODO: override finalizer only if 'Dispose(bool disposing)' has code to free unmanaged resources
  // ~ElementVirtualizer()
  // {
  //     // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
  //     Dispose(disposing: false);
  // }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
    Dispose(disposing: true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }
}
```

Because going down this route will modify the existing visual tree, there is a chance to cause layout disturbances (briefly but likely visible).
To solve this I recommend to use a custom print dialog that displays the output as a print preview. This way you can gracefully render the element that you want to print.

The following example is based on the above `VirtualElementHost` and shows how to use a custom print dialog in order to create a custom print flow that allows to display a preview.
The example also shows how to implement the flow without violating MVVM and modifies your existing types accordingly:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private async void OnPrintReportButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (this.Resources["PrintSampleChartDataTemplate"] is not DataTemplate template)
  {
    throw new Exception("Could not find a DataTemplate for printing.");
  }

  // Create the data model for the e.g. graphical report that should be printed
  var contentModel = new ViewModel();
  var contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter
  {
    Content = contentModel,
    ContentTemplate = template,
  };

  // Let the custom print dialog control the print flow (show a preview, interact with the user and finally print it)
  var previewPrintDialog = new PrintPreviewDialog(contentPresenter);
  _ = previewPrintDialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources> 
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PrintSampleChartDataTemplate"
                  DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel}">
      <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding Series}"
                          AnimationsSpeed="0"
                          Width="800"
                          Height="600" Loaded="CartesianChart_Loaded" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  
  <Button Content="Print Report"
          Click="OnPrintReportButtonClicked" />
</Window>
```

**PrintPreviewDialog.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class PrintPreviewDialog : Window
{
  private FrameworkElement PrintItem { get; }
  private ElementLifetimeScope ElementLifetimeScope { get; set; }

  public PrintPreviewDialog(FrameworkElement printItem)
  {
    this.PrintItem = printItem;
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override async void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnInitialized(e);
    this.ElementLifetimeScope = this.PreviewHost.CreateVirtualizedElementLifetimeScope();
    await this.ElementLifetimeScope.LoadElementAsync(this.PrintItem);
  }

  private async void OnPrintButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var dialog = new PrintDialog();
    bool? dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog();
    if (!dialogResult.GetValueOrDefault())
    {
      return;
    }

    var paginator = new ChartPaginator(this.PrintItem, new System.Windows.Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight));
    dialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "test");
    this.DialogResult = true;
    this.ElementLifetimeScope.Dispose();
    Close();
  }
}
```

**PrintPreviewDialog.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Button IsDefault="True"
              Click="OnPrintButtonClicked" 
              Content="Ok" />
      <Button IsCancel="True" 
              Content="Cancel" />
    </StackPanel>

    <local:VirtualElementHost x:Name="PreviewHost" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**ChartPaginator.cs**

```cs
public class ChartPaginator : DocumentPaginator
{
  private Visual PageContent { get; }

  public ChartPaginator(Visual item, Size pageSize)
  {
    this.PageContent = item;
    this.PageSize = pageSize;
  }

  public override bool IsPageCountValid => true;
  public override int PageCount => 1;
  public override Size PageSize { get; set; }
  public override IDocumentPaginatorSource Source => null;
  public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber) => new DocumentPage(this.PageContent, this.PageSize, new Rect(), new Rect());
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ViewModel() => this.Series = new ISeries[]
  {
    new LineSeries<double>
    {
      Values = new double[] { 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 6 },
      Fill = null
    }
  };

  public ISeries[] Series { get; set; }
}
```